# modifying SQLite schema

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a SQLite db I include in the assets folder. I installed the app on a device. I understand it gets copied into memory and everything works OK.

Now I changed the structure of a table in the SQLite db using the SQL Browser. So I replaced the one in the assets folder with the new one and incremented my app version number.

From reading questions I understand that when I upgrade the app on a device the "onUpgrade" will be called and it seems I must first delete the previous SQL db, since it's not the correct structure.

Do I just delete the older version when  "onUpgrage" is called and then do what?

Comment: Please see
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505900/sqliteopenhelper-onupgrade-confusion-android

Answer (score 0):

Its better to uninstall your previous application and install the new one with changed database structrue.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention, its for android.Tag says its android.So i think will work just fine