# Android updating database in assets folder

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an app receiving its data from a database in the assets folder. Now everyone has the app on their phones I want to update the database. I have the new database ready to go on a server, but how to I get the updated database into the assets folder on their phones. All only if they want to update of course???

Cheers,

Mike.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SQLiteOpenHelper` constructor has an `version` argument. If you supply some number that is bigger than the existing database version in phones memory, `onUpgrade` function will run after `getWritableDatabase` is called. Inside `onUpgrade` you should handle updating your database.

Some example code here:
[Question about onUpgrade method android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7273751/448625)

Comment: Thanks Vegas, Is that the only way it can be done??? I would prefer this to be an option and they not have to update the whole app, therefore not have the updates available icon sitting in their tray. Right now I have 15 updates available and I keep having to clear them or uninstall the apps! People don’t like apps telling them there are updates available.

Comment: Inside `onUpgrade` you can launch a message box asking user for approval.

Comment: Thanks Vegas, you sent me in the right direction and I get it now. It’s one of those programming things that are a pain to test, like email forms! Cheers, Mike.